# Log4j version 2 set root logging level from Java?

Tags: java, log4j2

In log4j version 2, how does one accomplish what previous versions of log4j did when called from Java code thus:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel( Level.TRACE );
```

I want, depending on a utility's command-line option, to turn on tracing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME); 
loggerConfig.setLevel(level);
ctx.updateLoggers();
```